# Best way to store user information in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I am developing an app that requires a user to register and log in. Currently to date I have been storing their userID (retrieved from an API), username and hashed password (plus a few other bits of information) in user defaults however after doing some research on security, users are able to modify these defaults as they are stored in a text file.

My concern is that I would not want a user to change the userID and access other users information. What would be the best way to secure the data in the app?

All information is retrieved from an online API and I am not using Core Data.

I have looked in to Keychain but would this be overkill to store userID?

Comment: If you want secure storage of a small piece of data locally then KeyChain is  probably the best solution.  It certainly isn't overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keychain would not be overkill, that kind of thing is what it's for.

Really though it sounds like a bad security problem in your API.  If the user can login and can then access the data of every other user via the API and then if they fiddle with some values, that's no good.

Comment: Thanks. The API is in its early development stages and we will cross the security implementation soon but I come from a web background where setting sessions and IDs is usually OK. I just haven't seen sessions in apps yet.